# Does Facebook send live data on ngrok callback url?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to receive live lead_gen data on my rgrok callback URL.

I am able to receive test data on ngrok callback URL but I am not receiving any live data on it, My app is reviewed and is live mode.

Comment: As long as you handled the setup steps correctly (verification challenge), Facebook does not care what URL you use - it needs to have SSL and be available from their servers, but that’s all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Facebook sends live data on ngrok, the problem I had was that my business was not verified thats why I couldn't receive callbacks from facebook API.